# Best word to describe what a педант does?

Tags: выбор-слова

What would be the best word to describe what a педант does?

In the following list there are some people along with the things normally do:

> Мазохист занимается мазохизмом.
>   Казуист занимается казуистикой.
>   Альпинист занимается альпиизмом.
>   Пацифист занимается пацифизмом.
>   Ростовщик занимается ростовщичеством.
>   Бизмесмен занимается бизнесом.

Педант занимается ... ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Педант *предаётся* педантизму, точности, аккуратности.
>
> Педант *практикует* педантизм, точность, аккуратность.

Нельзя использовать здесь слово `занимается`, поскольку педант - это не занятие, не профессия, не род деятельности, педанты не объединяются в клубы, цеха, гильдии, это склад характера, особенность личности, склонность. Невозможно заниматься педантизмом, это всё равно, что сказать, что неряха занимается неряшливостью, или честный человек занимается честностью.

You cannot use the word `занимается` here, because a pedant is not a profession, not a trade, not an occupation, pedants do not have their clubs, guilds, it is a character trend, a peculiarity of personality, a tendency. It is impossible to be engaged in pedantry, it is like saying that a slob is engaged in sloppiness, or an honest man is engaged in honesty.

Comment: But what about "Ты занимаешься формализмом" or "Ты занимаешься казуистикой"? As far as I know, neither формалист, nor a казуист is a trade, occupation or a profession, isn't it?

Comment: @brilliant - Формализм and казуистика have to do sometheng with science, with philosophy, for example. So, I think, "Ты занимаешься формализмом" and "Ты занимаешься казуистикой" refer to that, to the interpretation of facts, dealing with information, while педантизм  refers to habits of accuracy in general, like shining boots or taking care of one's nails.

Comment: @brilliant: *формализм* and *казуистика* in you examples are practices (*формализм* probably being confused with *формалистика*). I haven't understood *пацифист занимается пацифизмом* in you example though: how exactly does one actively practice pacifism? I would say *пацифист придерживается принципов пацифизма* or *пацифист исповедует пацифизм*.

Comment: @Quassnoi - That's a good point, I was just going to write a similar comment. Мазохизм, альпинизм, ростовщичество, бизнес are either a process, or an activity. Казуистика and формализм are methodological approaches. But pedantism is a feature of one's chatacter, like attentivenes, kindness, honesty, etc., you cannot practice them.

Comment: No, you can practice. Just you cannot use 'занимается ...'. Another example: "Умница умничает", not "занимается умничеством".

Comment: "Ты занимаешься формализмом"  => "Ты страдаешь формализмом"

Comment: @revoua: did you mean *умник*? Also, I can imagine *не занимайся умничаньем*, though now that we have a shorter verb *не умничай* that would sound pretty ostentatious.

Answer (score 4):

```
Педант педантствует.
```

Means nit-picking.

Comment: Welcome to Russian.SE. While your answer provides useful contribution, short one- or two-line answers are generally discouraged. Try to incorporate more sources or examples (hint: search the corpus for appropriate use in a reputable text).